# MainActivity становится видимым

Tags: android

Подскажите есть какой-нибудь который позволяет узнать что activity сейчас открыта? Мне нужно при закрытии второй активности передавать на главную Activity информацию

Comment: Вам нужен onAcitityResult

Comment: Понял. Кажется то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

А зачем? При закрытии просто передавайте свои данные через `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
intent.putString("name", "Ваня");
startActivity(intent);
```

В активности `Second` получайте Ваню:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: Мне нужен обратный процесс. Со второй передавать в главную